# My print statements aren't working in a nested if statement

Tags: python

I am trying to make a very basic python rock paper scissors game. But, any of the print statements I write in an if statement aren't working.

My code is this:

```
import random

round_count = input("How many rounds would you like to play? ")
score = 0

for i in range(int(round_count)):
    computer_choice = random.choices(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])
    player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()`your text`

    if computer_choice == player_choice:
        print("Tie")
    else:
        if computer_choice == "paper" and player_choice == "scissors":
            print("Scissors beats paper. You win!")
            score += 1
        if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "paper":
            print("Scissors beats paper. You lost.")
        if computer_choice == "rock" and player_choice == "scissors":
            print("Rock beats scissors. You lost.")
        if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "rock":
            print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
            score += 1
            
print(f"Your score is {str(score)}/{str(round_count)}")
```

Any of the print statements in the for loop won't print. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: If you were to actually print the value of `computer_choice`, you'd see it's not one of the strings you're comparing it to - instead, it's a list containing such a string.  You want `random.choice()`, rather than `random.choices()`.  Also, you're not handling the two cases of rock vs. paper.

Comment: @jasonharper that was actually the issue in my program . I didn't account for rock vs. paper. Thank you so much for bringing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hii man anther than you're error you forget about the case of paper and rock from both sides. Try this code
import random

```
round_count = input("How many rounds would you like to play? ")
score = 0

for i in range(int(round_count)):
    computer_choice = random.choices(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])
    player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()
    computer_choice=computer_choice[0]
    #print(player_choice)
    if computer_choice == player_choice:
        print("Tie")
    else:
        if computer_choice == "paper" and player_choice == "scissors":
            print("Scissors beats paper. You win!")
            score += 1
        if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "paper":
         print("Scissors beats paper. You lost.")
        if computer_choice == "rock" and player_choice == "scissors":
            print("Rock beats scissors. You lost.")
        if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "rock":
            print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
        if computer_choice == "rock" and player_choice == "paper":
            print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
        if computer_choice == "paper" and player_choice == "rock":
             print("Rock beats scissors. You lost.")
            score += 1

print(f"Your score is {str(score)}/{str(round_count)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`computer_choice = random.choices(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])`

```
import random

round_count = input("How many rounds would you like to play? ")
score = 0

for i in range(int(round_count)):
    computer_choice = random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])
    player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()

    if computer_choice == player_choice:
        print("Tie")
    else:
        if computer_choice == "paper" and player_choice == "scissors":
            print("Scissors beats paper. You win!")
            score += 1
        if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "paper":
            print("Scissors beats paper. You lost.")
        if computer_choice == "rock" and player_choice == "scissors":
            print("Rock beats scissors. You lost.")
        if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "rock":
            print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
            score += 1

print(f"Your score is {score}/{round_count}")
```

Also always check for spacing, using tab and four spaces can break the code too. Stick to one wether it's spaces or tabs only.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning list for computer's choice and comparing it to Yingle input value from the user you need to change this

```
computer_choice = random.choices(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])
```

to

```
computer_choice = random.choices(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])[0]`
```

then the full code will be

```
import random

round_count = input("How many rounds would you like to play? ")
score = 0
computer_choice = random.choices(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])[0]
player_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ").lower()

if computer_choice == player_choice:
    print("Tie")
else:
    if computer_choice == "paper" and player_choice == "scissors":
        print("Scissors beats paper. You win!")
        score += 1
    if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "paper":
        print("Scissors beats paper. You lost.")
    if computer_choice == "rock" and player_choice == "scissors":
        print("Rock beats scissors. You lost.")
    if computer_choice == "scissors" and player_choice == "rock":
        print("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
        score += 1
```